# Extract array from a string return

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Can I extract an Array from a string variable:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: YYYYYYYYY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 163
X-OAPI-Request-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
{
  "token_type": "berber",
  "access_token": "XXXXXXXXYYYYYYY",
  "expires_in": "7776000"
}
```

I want to get the array with token_type, access_token, expires_in.

Comment: I do not see any array here

Comment: do you want to convert your object to an array, that is what you are asking?

Comment: You need to explain how you're getting this, and in which of the two languages you've tagged that you want to process it in. Also, you need to include *what you've tried so far*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of a json, so you can just trim off the part that is not json and decode it with json_decode.

```
$arr = json_decode(substr($str,strpos($str,"{")), true);
Var_dump($arr);
```

Here I send from "{" to end of string to the json_decode, returns:
https://3v4l.org/r8VgO

Answer (score 1):

You can write small string cutter and then convert it into a `json`

```js
const str = `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: YYYYYYYYY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 163
X-OAPI-Request-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
{
  "token_type": "berber",
  "access_token": "XXXXXXXXYYYYYYY",
  "expires_in": "7776000"
}`;

let result = str.substring(str.indexOf('{'), str.indexOf('}') + 1);
result = JSON.parse(result);

console.log(result);
console.log(result.token_type)
```

Comment: Amazing how we give the same answer in different language. It would be wrong to not upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example IF you are loading the content from an external website:

```
<?php
    $page = file_get_contents( "http://urlyouused" );
    $array = json_decode( $page, true );
    print_r( $array);
?>
```

The [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will load that web page you showed the results from and put the contents. The [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will decode the JSON object into an object normally. But with the 'true' flag it will output an array instead of an object.

Both PHP and Javascript are tagged for this post so this would be a solution for PHP. I think someone posted an answer for Javascript.

**EDIT**

Either the post changed or I misread (most likely) about starting with a string. Here is a possible solution if you are starting with a string:

```
preg_match( "#(\{.*\})#is", $string, $results );
$array = json_decode( $results[0], true );
print_r( $array );
```

Using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get just the JSON object. The s flag is needed so that the line returns don't end the search. Basically it is trying to capture anything within the curly brackets and the brackets themselves which make the JSON object. The true flag in the json_decode again returns an array instead of an object.

Comment: That won't work, not in PHP at least. https://3v4l.org/BKbfu

Comment: Hmmm. I actually set it up and ran the script and it worked for me in PHP.

Comment: Odd. It shouldn't since it's not a real json, at least not at the start

Comment: As a string it's not. But if pulling it from a web server, the string would not include the headers, only the body. I put in a second answer that accounts for only having a string, but I wanted to include my first answer in case the OP might be first loading it from a web page (indicated by the http headers at the top).